# Exception when loading related objects. Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, exception

I am getting an exception when loading related objects in my db. I am loading all my `MatchData` objects and I want to iterate them with a foreach.

The objects that I'm loading is:

MatchData Class:

```
public class MatchData
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    private List<PlayerData> blueTeam = new List<PlayerData>();
    private List<PlayerData> redTeam = new List<PlayerData>();

    [InverseProperty("MatchDataBlue")]
    public virtual List<PlayerData> BlueTeam
    {
        get { return blueTeam; }
        set { blueTeam = value; }
    }
    [InverseProperty("MatchDataRed")]
    public virtual List<PlayerData> RedTeam
    {
        get { return redTeam; }
        set { redTeam = value; }
    }
}
```

PlayerData Class:

```
public class PlayerData
{

    // properties
    [Key]
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Player Player { get; set; }
    public virtual MatchData MatchDataBlue { get; set; }
    public virtual MatchData MatchDataRed { get; set; }
}
```

Here is how I load them the MatchData objects:

```
using (DBBooneContext db = new DBBooneContext())
{
    var smth = db.MatchData
        .Include(md => md.BlueTeam)
        .ToList();
}
```

DBContext

```
class DBBooneContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Player> Player { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PlayerData> PlayerData { get; set; }
    public DbSet<MatchData> MatchData { get; set; }
}
```

When I run the ToList i get the exception:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll

full exception:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The class 'Boonekamp.ClassCollection.PlayerData' has no parameterless constructor.
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DelegateFactory.GetConstructorForType(Type type)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Translator.TranslatorVisitor.Emit_ConstructEntity(EntityType oSpaceType, IEnumerable`1 propertyBindings, Expression entityKeyReader, Expression entitySetReader, TranslatorArg arg, EntityProxyTypeInfo proxyTypeInfo)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Translator.TranslatorVisitor.Visit(EntityColumnMap columnMap, TranslatorArg arg)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.EntityColumnMap.Accept[TResultType,TArgType](ColumnMapVisitorWithResults`2 visitor, TArgType arg)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Translator.TranslatorVisitor.HandleSpandexRecord(RecordColumnMap columnMap, TranslatorArg arg, RowType spanRowType)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Translator.TranslatorVisitor.Visit(RecordColumnMap columnMap, TranslatorArg arg)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.RecordColumnMap.Accept[TResultType,TArgType](ColumnMapVisitorWithResults`2 visitor, TArgType arg)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Translator.TranslatorVisitor.ProcessCollectionColumnMap(CollectionColumnMap columnMap, TranslatorArg arg, ColumnMap discriminatorColumnMap, Object discriminatorValue)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Translator.TranslatorVisitor.Visit(DiscriminatedCollectionColumnMap columnMap, TranslatorArg arg)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.DiscriminatedCollectionColumnMap.Accept[TResultType,TArgType](ColumnMapVisitorWithResults`2 visitor, TArgType arg)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Translator.TranslatorVisitor.AcceptWithMappedType(TranslatorVisitor translatorVisitor, ColumnMap columnMap)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Translator.TranslatorVisitor.HandleSpandexRecord(RecordColumnMap columnMap, TranslatorArg arg, RowType spanRowType)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Translator.TranslatorVisitor.Visit(RecordColumnMap columnMap, TranslatorArg arg)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.RecordColumnMap.Accept[TResultType,TArgType](ColumnMapVisitorWithResults`2 visitor, TArgType arg)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Translator.TranslatorVisitor.ProcessCollectionColumnMap(CollectionColumnMap columnMap, TranslatorArg arg, ColumnMap discriminatorColumnMap, Object discriminatorValue)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Translator.TranslatorVisitor.ProcessCollectionColumnMap(CollectionColumnMap columnMap, TranslatorArg arg)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Translator.TranslatorVisitor.Visit(SimpleCollectionColumnMap columnMap, TranslatorArg arg)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.SimpleCollectionColumnMap.Accept[TResultType,TArgType](ColumnMapVisitorWithResults`2 visitor, TArgType arg)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Translator.TranslateColumnMap[T](ColumnMap columnMap, MetadataWorkspace workspace, SpanIndex spanIndex, MergeOption mergeOption, Boolean streaming, Boolean valueLayer)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Translator.TranslateColumnMap(Translator translator, Type elementType, ColumnMap columnMap, MetadataWorkspace workspace, SpanIndex spanIndex, MergeOption mergeOption, Boolean streaming, Boolean valueLayer)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlanFactory.Prepare(ObjectContext context, DbQueryCommandTree tree, Type elementType, MergeOption mergeOption, Boolean streaming, Span span, IEnumerable`1 compiledQueryParameters, AliasGenerator aliasGenerator)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.EntitySqlQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__6()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__5()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Boonekamp.ClassCollection.Player.getStats(Predicate`1 predicate) in d:\Dropbox\code\c#\Boonekamp\Boonekamp\ClassCollection\Player.cs:line 49

Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
```

I have absolutely no clue how to solve this issue. Any ideas?

Comment: It seems odd that a call to `ToList()` would cause an invocation error in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll. My guess is it's a different issue. Can you show your DBBooneContext implementation (including any conventions and/or configurations you have defined)?

Comment: @BrianDriscoll: The queation is updated for you :)

Comment: Unfortunately it's not as illuminating as I'd hoped. I'm wondering if there's an underlying DB issue. What does your DB schema look like? Does anything change if you remove either the `Include` or `ToList` calls from your `using` block?

Comment: Is there an inner exception by any chance? Can you provide the full output of the exception (i.e. ex.ToString())?

Comment: @BrianDriscoll It seems it is the .Include that is causing the problem. When i only run tostring() and not include() i dont get the exception. I'm not sure how to show you the scheme when using code first.

Comment: Does `PlayerData` class has a parameter-less constructor? Does it have any constructor defined at all?

Comment: @CraigW. The full exception is updated in the question.

Comment: @haim770 it has one constructor: `public PlayerData(Player player){using (DBBooneContext db = new DBBooneContext()){ Player = player; }}` which is the only one.

Comment: BTW, why are you creating a new `DBBooneContext` instance (wrapping the `Player` assignment) that is not used at all? Also, you may be introducing a serious concurrency and multiple-contexts change-tracking problems.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The inner exception says it all:

> The class 'Boonekamp.ClassCollection.PlayerData' has no parameterless
>   constructor

Change your `PlayerData` to:

```
[Obsolete("Only needed for serialization and materialization", true)]
public PlayerData() {}

public PlayerData(Player player)
{
}
```

This way, you do have a parameter-less constructor that Entity Framework will be able to use during initialization. Yet, you prevent using that constructor in code using the `[Obsolete]` attribute.

Comment: Ohh god i need to start read those inner exception.

Thank you so much Haim! I got it working

Comment: you can mark your constructor as private. no need for the oblolete attribute. as here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31543487/1806239.