# LINQ error: "<object> has no parameterless constructor."

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a class method `GetMS()` as defined below, but when the method is called I get an error stating `'SLRD' has no parameterless constructor.` I don't understand why a parameterless constructor is even being called. What's wrong here?

```
public class SLR : BaseEntity
{
    // ...
    public virtual ICollection<SLRD> ChildRequests { get; set; }
}

public SLRD GetMS()
{
    return ChildRequests.First(c => c.Type == SLRTypes.MS);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you get is pretty clear. You missed to define a parameterless constructor.

```
public class SLR : BaseEntity
{
    public SLR() : base
    {
    }

    // ...
    public virtual ICollection<SLRD> ChildRequests { get; set; }
}
```

The reason this is happens is the fact that your base class may have a parameterless constructor. So you have to define one for the derived class, `SLR`.

Comment: Do you know why? I am curious.

Comment: @Petrichor http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31543255/why-must-i-have-a-parameterless-constructor-for-code-first-entity-framework

Comment: You only have to define a parameterless constructor if a non-default constructor is defined, which the question does not indicate.

Comment: Perfect, I didn't realize I could just make an empty constructor and have it still work properly. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

> I don't understand why a parameterless constructor is even being called.

My guess is that you are populating `ChildRequests` lazily via a Linq/EF query, so the objects are not created until you iterate over them (which is done as part of the `First` method).  At that point, EF tries to create an instance using a parameterless constructor which does not exist.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the explanation of why it's needed!

Comment: This is the right answer. I encountered this issue when enabling lazy loading. Explaining why it happens enables the coder to make the correct fix in context with their own application, rather than do something unwanted.