# ASP.net Linq Query InvalidOperationException: The class '' has no parameterless constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

Title pretty much explains it, went away for a few hours, came back and did some coding, ran it, didn't work. So I practically cleared it. Now i am receiving this error. InvalidOperationException: The class 'ClientApp.Models.Product' has no parameterless constructor. And it's highlighting this code

```
List<Product> query = (from p in _db.Products
                                   where list.Contains(p.SubCategoryID)
                                   select p).ToList();
```

Full method

```
public List<Product> GetProducts()
{
    var _db = new ClientApp.Models.ProductContext();
    IEnumerable<int> list = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
    List<Product> query = (from p in _db.Products
                           where list.Contains(p.SubCategoryID)
                           select p).ToList();
    return query;

}
```

Product class (using ADO.NET Entity)

```
[Table("Product")]
    public partial class Product
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Product(int productId)
        {
            OrderDetails = new HashSet<OrderDetail>();
        }

        public int ProductID { get; set; }

        public int RetailerID { get; set; }

        public int SubCategoryID { get; set; }


        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string ProductName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(255)]
        public string ProductDescription { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "money")]
        public decimal Price { get; set; }

        public int UnitsInStock { get; set; }

        public byte[] Picture { get; set; }

        public bool? IsDiscontinued { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }

        public virtual ProductSubCategory ProductSubCategory { get; set; }
    }
```

Full error code is as follows:
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: 'Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'
InvalidOperationException: The class 'ClientApp.Models.Product' has no parameterless constructor.

This was working flawlessly up until a few hours ago, BEFORE I made some changes , and now its completely broken. I've done as much backtracking as I can to fix this, can't find any solutions on google either...Any ideas?

Comment: I suggest taking a close look at your Product class and making sure it has a default, public constructor

Comment: Um, what did you change? That might help in troubleshooting the issue.

Comment: @JayV, without parameters.

Comment: look into this solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31594438/linq-error-object-has-no-parameterless-constructor

Comment: @VDWWD From MSDN: [A constructor that takes no parameters is called a default constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-constructors). Did I get this wrong and grossly misunderstand the explanation?

Comment: @invrt the Exception is explicit saying that there is no parameterless constructor. 
public Product()
        {
            OrderDetails = new HashSet<OrderDetail>();
        }

Adding this should do the trick!

Comment: @FernandoMoreira Whoa wtf, that solved it, I don't understand why it did though? It's pretty much repeating the code @ the top of the class

Comment: @invrt do you think that before you were doing the opposite ? searching in the list for the products and not for the products in the list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fix your problem change

```
public Product(int productId)
{
    OrderDetails = new HashSet<OrderDetail>();
}
```

to

```
public Product()
{
    OrderDetails = new HashSet<OrderDetail>();
}
```

The `productId` parameter was not being used in the constructor and therefore does not *need* to be there.

As to why it used to work and why it doesn't now, the only suggestion I can offer is that there used to be a default constructor. Either you accidently deleted it, added the productId parameter to it, or maybe it was in the other partial declaration of the class.

Edit:
In addition, if there was NO constructor at all (with or without parameters), then the C# compiler will add one for you. A Default one, that takes no parameters, has no functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Your error code: "The class 'ClientApp.Models.Product' **has no parameterless constructor.**"

Try to set parameterless constructor.

For example:

```
 public Product()
 {

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework requires an empty default constructor (that is, a constructor without parameters) in order to initialize the entity (Product in this case) during query operations made to your underlying database.

Simply add an empty constructor as others have suggested or remove the parameter from your existing constructor. Accessibility doesn't matter to EF so unless you want to be able to initialize the class with the default constructor in other places in your code it can be set as private to keep others from accessing the class in an unintended manner.

```
    private Product()
    {

    }
```

**Why is this happening?**

For whatever reason a non-empty constructor was introduced on your Product entity. When a non-empty constructor is present the compiler believes that you didn't want to expose the default parameter-less constructor that is always present on C# classes when no specific constructor is defined. Since the compiler believes you didn't want the default constructor anymore it didn't add one in for you. EF requires a default parameterless constructor and, unfortunately, will only show itself at runtime.