# Can't configure nested owned entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

My class structure is as follows:

```
internal sealed class ClientEntity {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    
    public CompanyAddressesEntity? CompanyAddresses { get; set; }

    public ClientEntity(Guid id, CompanyAddressesEntity? companyAddresses)
    {
        Id = id;
        CompanyAddresses = companyAddresses;
    }
}

internal sealed class CompanyAddressesEntity {
    public AddressEntity PrimaryAddress { get; set; }
    
    public AddressEntity? SecondaryAddress { get; set; }

    public CompanyAddressesEntity(AddressEntity primaryAddress, AddressEntity? secondaryAddress)
    {
        PrimaryAddress = primaryAddress;
        SecondaryAddress = secondaryAddress;
    }
}

internal sealed class AddressEntity {
    public string FirstAddressLine { get; set; }

    public AddressEntity(string firstAddressLine)
    {
        FirstAddressLine = firstAddressLine;
    }
}
```

And the entity configurations looks like this:

```
internal class ClientEntityConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ClientEntity>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ClientEntity> builder)
    {
        builder
            .OwnsOne(
                p => p.CompanyAddresses,
                addressBuilder =>
                {
                    addressBuilder.OwnsOne(
                        a => a.PrimaryAddress, 
                        addressBuilder =>
                        {
                            addressBuilder.Property(a => a.FirstAddressLine);
                        });
                    addressBuilder.OwnsOne(
                        a => a.SecondaryAddress,
                        addressBuilder =>
                        {
                            addressBuilder.Property(a => a.FirstAddressLine);
                        });
                });
    }
}
```

However, when I try running the migration Entity Framework complains:

> No suitable constructor was found for entity type
> 'CompanyAddressesEntity'. The following constructors had parameters
> that could not be bound to properties of the entity type:
> Cannot bind 'primaryAddress', 'secondaryAddress' in 'CompanyAddressesEntity(AddressEntity primaryAddress, AddressEntity
> secondaryAddress)' Note that only mapped properties can be bound to
> constructor parameters. Navigations to related entities, including
> references to owned types, cannot be bound.

What does this all mean? Is there a way to make this code work?

Answer (score 0):

When you defined an Entity in an Entity class, you need to ensure that the entire thing is public and accessable (https://stackoverflow.com/a/63939094/20228825).

So in your case I would try changing `internal sealed class AddressEntity` to `public class AddressEntity`

Also if you're using an older version of EF, try creating a default constructor without parameters.

Comment: Actually changing the visibility of my classes didn't do nothing but adding a default, private ctor made it work...