# 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, visual-studio

I'm calling this method by `CascadingDropDownListFor` and I'm getting an exception:

> An exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code

```
public JsonResult GetRaca(string especieId)
{
    int esp = Convert.ToInt32(especieId);
    var rac = db.Raca.Where(c => c.EspecieId == esp).ToList();
    var racas = new List<SelectListItem>();
    foreach (var ra in rac)
    {
        var racaConteudo = db.RacaConteudo
            .Where(c => c.RacaId == ra.RacaId)
            .Where(c => c.IdiomaId == 1)
            .First(); // <= The exception occurred here

        racas.Add(new SelectListItem 
        {
            Text = racaConteudo.RacaId.ToString(), 
            Value = racaConteudo.NomePopular 
        });
    }

    return Json(racas, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

The entity:

```
[Table("RacasConteudo")]
    public class RacaConteudo
    {
        public RacaConteudo(long RacaId, string NomeCientifico, string NomePopular, long IdiomaId)
        {
            this.RacaId = RacaId;
            this.NomeCientifico = NomeCientifico;
            this.NomePopular = NomePopular;
            this.IdiomaId = IdiomaId;
        }

        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public long RacaConteudoId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("RacaId")]
        public virtual Raca Raca { get; set; }
        public long RacaId { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [Display(Name = "Nome Cientifico")]
        public string NomeCientifico { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [Display(Name = "Nome Popular")]
        public string NomePopular { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("IdiomaId")]
        [Display(Name = "Idioma")]
        public virtual Idioma Idioma { get; set; }
        public long IdiomaId { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show your entity objects? Do they all have parameterless constructors for example?

Comment: What is the type of the `db.RacaContuendo` property?

Comment: What's the **inner exception** text?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22666607/exception-when-loading-related-objects-entity-framework

Answer (score -1, accepted):

***Remove parameterized  constructor*** `public RacaConteudo(long RacaId, ..., long IdiomaId)`, and make the class ***partial***.

```
[Table("RacasConteudo")]
public partial class RacaConteudo
        ^^^^^
{
   /* public RacaConteudo(...)  {} */

   [Key]
   [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
   public long RacaConteudoId { get; set; }
   ....
}
```

Based on your updated question, *Raca* and *RacaConteudo* have relationship.

If so, you could even retrieve the desired result in ***single query*** *which is a lot faster than querying multiple RacaConteudos for each and every Raca*.

```
public JsonResult GetRaca(string especieId)
{
    int esp = Convert.ToInt32(especieId);

    var result = (from c in db.RacaConteudo
        where c.Raca.EspecieId == esp && c.IdiomaId == 1
        select new {Text = c.NomePopular, Value = c.RacaId.ToString()}).ToList();    

    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: I have no problem with suggesting better ways to do things, but when I wrote that, your answer had nothing about the parameterless constructors which *does* answer the question. However, now the question is a [dupe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22666607/exception-when-loading-related-objects-entity-framework) and should have been closed as such.

Comment: @DavidG No, I did not. There is nothing wrong in your comment; besides, *I appreciate your feedback*. Down-votes in question and answers might have triggered the moderator attention.